# showing maximum number per columns with php myadmin

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone help me to finish the program that I make? I stopped almost a week because I didn't find the answer.

This is the problem:

I have a table with columns named `vr`, `vs` and `vt`. I want to display the maximum value of the `vr`, `vt` and `vs` columns, so not the vr, vs or vt columns only. but compares the maximum value of columns vr, vt, and vs.

[image: Click to see image]

Maybe anyone here can help me, I will be very grateful for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the max from the three values you can use.

**Using** [IF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html)

```
SELECT 
nama, 
jam, 
IF ( (vr >= vs and vr >= vt), vr , IF ( (vs >= vr and vs >= vt ), vs, vt) ) as maxValue
FROM mytable
```

**Or** [GREATEST()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest)

```
SELECT 
nama, 
jam, 
GREATEST(vr,vs,vt) as maxValue
FROM mytable
```

Comment: thanks, now i can continue my work :)

Comment: You are welcome.. please up vote and Mark as accepted if that helps you

Answer (score 0):

Use Greatest function for chossing from the columns

```
SELECT GREATEST(vr,vs,vt) FROM yourtable;
```

Comment: thanks, its work.. now i can continue my work :)

Comment: please upvote the answer if it works. Thanks